# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error in symfony2

Tags: symfony

I got following error when i called stored procedure in symfony2

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error
500 Internal Server Error - PDOException

I have following code in conroller:

```
public function indexAction($name) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $query = $em->createNativeQuery('CALL sp_demoproc_insert ()', new ResultSetMapping());
    $result = $query->execute();
    $em->flush();

    return $this->render('HomeHomeBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('name' => $name));
}
```

and stored procedure is as follows,

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS tmp.sp_demoproc_insert;
CREATE PROCEDURE tmp.`sp_demoproc_insert`()
INSERT INTO `tmp`.`details` (
`id` ,
`name`
)
VALUES (
'11', 'xyz'
);

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error when trying to call a stored procedure.
Then I saw [this page](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#examples)
So I tried this one and it worked for me :

$em->getConnection()->executeUpdate('CALL YourStoredProc ()');

Answer (score 0):

Check https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/5497#issuecomment-162372454

> **createNativeQuery() is only for SELECT statements.**
>
> Use $em->getConnection()->executeUpdate() for UPDATE, DELETE or INSERT statements.
>
> This is a documentation issue.